# Prove: intersection of finite sets is not empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a compact set, and $\{{A_{i}\}_{i\in I}}$ a group of closed sets such that $\cup_{i\in I}\{{A_{i}}\}=X$.
>
> Let assume that for any finite group $\{A_{i_k}\}_{k=1}^{m}$ then $\cap_{k=1}^{m}A_{i_k}\neq \emptyset$
>
> Prove: $\cap_{i\in I}A_{i}\neq \emptyset$

let assume $A_{i}=\emptyset$ therefore there is $a$ such that $a\in\cap_{i=1}^{m}A_{i_k}$ but $a\notin \cap_{i\in I}A_{i}$

For every $a\in A_{i}$ there is a squance in which $a$ is its limit, As all ${A_{i}}$ are closed and as such it contains its limit point, but $a\notin \cap_{i\in I}A_{i}$ so $\cap_{i\in I}A_{i}$ is not closed

How should I continue? moreover, It seems that the fact that $X$ is compact and in particular bounded in not used as an argument in the proof

Comment: What do you mean by $$\cap_{i=1}^{m}A_{ik}\neq \emptyset$$ Where is that k comming from? Any conditions on m? So many questions…

Comment: If some $A_i=\emptyset$ then any intersection with this set is empty.

Comment: @Gono I have edited the question , forgot a phrase

Comment: Your partial proof has many logical and/or strategic errors, so it will be very hard to correct it without starting over completely. For instance, "let assume $A_i = \emptyset$" is the incorrect start of the proof. The correct start would be "let assume $\cap_{i \in I} A_i = \emptyset$". For another, "For every $a \in A_i$ there is a sequence in which which $a$ is its limit" is a useless statement, because this is true for any subset containing $a$, regardless of whether that subset is open or closed or anything else.

Comment: Observe that the sets $N_p:=(\Bbb N_{\ge 2}\setminus p\Bbb N_{\ge 1})\times\{0\}^{n-1}\subset\Bbb R^n$ are closed, for $p\in\Bbb P$ where $\Bbb P$ is the sets of primes. It hold the condition that intersection of any finite set of $N_p$ is non-empty but $\bigcap_{p\in\Bbb P}N_p=\emptyset$, so you need compactness.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler counterexample: $A_n = [n, \infty)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ viewed as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there were a couple of errors in notation that I fixed: everywhere that you had $A_{ik}$, you should have had $A_{i_k}$, and $\{{A_i}_{i\in I}\}$ should have been $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$. (Also, the word *group* has a specific technical meaning in mathematics, so you should not use it as a synonym for *set$, *family*, *collection*, etc.)

Next, your hypotheses clearly require that the sets $A_i$ are all non-empty, so it makes no sense to assume that some $A_i=\varnothing$. If you’re trying for a proof by contradiction, you should assume that $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\varnothing$: *that* is the statement that is the negation of the desired conclusion. The rest is pretty well unsalvageable, I’m afraid, and you really need to start over. I’ll point you in the right direction.

This argument is most easily carried out using the definition of compactness: a set is compact if every open cover of it has a finite subcover. For each $i\in I$ let $U_i=\Bbb R^n\setminus A_i$. The sets $U_i$ are open (why?), and

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i=\bigcup_{i\in I}\left(\Bbb R^n\setminus A_i\right)=\Bbb R^n\setminus\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\Bbb R^n$$

if (as we are assuming in order to get a contradiction) $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=\varnothing$.

Now fix some specific $i_0\in I$; it doesn’t matter which one. Let $J=I\setminus\{i_0\}$.

- Show that $\{U_j:j\in J\}$ is an open cover of the compact set $A_{i_0}$.
- Conclude that there is a finite $J_0\subseteq J$ such that $A_{i_0}\subseteq\bigcup_{j\in J_0}A_j$.
- Use the previous result to find a finite collection of the sets $A_i$ whose intersection is empty, contradicting the hypothesis that all such finite intersections are *non*-empty.